# How to classify complex number in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, fft

I am working on EEG signal classification as university project. My aim is to classify “alpha” signals using SVM in python as I am concern with SSVEP based BCI method. So I choose only data from “alpha” column from the dataset. I preprocessed the signal using Butterworth filter to remove noises like EOG or eye muscle movements and then use FFT for feature extraction. 12 Hz cutoff is used in Butterworth filter as alpha wave is within that frequency and stored as “filtered_d.csv”.  I want to classify these feature using SVM for three class movement. I used FFT to extract features form these signal. I only shown one column for space limit. I get the result as complex number.

```
import pandas as pd
dataset=pd.read_csv("filtered_d.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
X=frame.drop(frame.columns[0], axis=1)
import numpy as np
sp = np.fft.fft(X['AF3 alpha std'].values)
print(sp)
```

Result:

[image]

My question is how do I classify these complex number with machine learning algorithm in python?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you're using these complex numbers for?

Comment: Maybe you can calculate magnitudes of complex numbers and use them in regression rather than classification setting?

Comment: i want to classify motor action from the data set https://www.kaggle.com/fabriciotorquato/eeg-data-from-hands-movement. I have applied butterworth filter to clear noise then applied FFT to get feature. FFT procedure generated these complex numbers.